# Use foverlaps in R with different reference value sets

Tags: r, data.table, overlap

I would like to construct a data frame where different values of blood pressure are assigned to each patient, taken from individual sets of intervals with predefined values. Although, I've successfully figured out how to pick the maximum value by sorting my data frame accordingly there's no inherent option within the package for using different sets of intervals per item ID so I thought I could make it work using a for loop, but without any apparent success.

Here's the data

```
>df1
PatientID  BloodPressure
Patient1   50
Patient2   100

>df2
IntervalID   PatientID   Low      High Index
Interval1    Patient1    10       80   20
Interval2    Patient1    70       120  40
Interval3    Patient1    90       150  60
Interval4    Patient1    160      260  80
Interval5    Patient1    200      300  100
Interval1    Patient2    10       80   30
Interval2    Patient2    70       120  50
Interval3    Patient2    90       150  70
Interval4    Patient2    160      260  90
Interval5    Patient2    200      300  110
```

And here's the actual code.

```
df1[, BloodPressure2 := BloodPressure]

for (Patient in unique(df1$PatientID)){
setkey(df2[df2$PatientID==Patient], Low, High)
d3=data.frame(t(matrix(unlist(foverlaps(df1[df1$PatientID==Patient], df2[df2$PatientID==Patient], by.x = c("BloodPressure", "BloodPressure2"), mult = "last", type = "within")[, .(PatientID, BloodPressure, Index, IntervalID)])))
d4=rbind(d4,d3)
}
```

The purpose is to create a data table/frame providing the interval ID and score for every patient. In that case d3 serves the role for storing the dataset for every case and concatenating to the d4 which should look like that...

```
>df4
PatientID  BloodPressure Index IntervalID
Patient1   50            20    Interval1
Patient2   100           70    Interval3
```

For the sake of solving the technical issue without violating patient confidentiality the data posted here is fictional.

Comment: `df2[df1, on = .(PatientID, Low <= BloodPressure, High >= BloodPressure), mult = "last"]` Should do.

Comment: For some reason I wasn't notified about the response and didn't report results. I tried it today and worked flawlessly. Thank you so much !!